# Using jQuery to show data from database in table not getting data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, table-display

I am trying crud operation using popup and jQuery but at start I only try to show data from database in table using jQuery Ajax. It does not show error message but not fetching data from database. I get undefined as data in table view.

This is the `site.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetTeams();
});

function GetTeams() {
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/Team/GetTeams',
            type: 'Get',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == null || response == undefined || response.length ==0) {
                    var object = '';
                    object += '<tr>';
                    object += '<td class="colspan=5"> ' + 'No Team Exists' + '</td>';
                    object += '</td>';
                    object += '</tr>';

                    $('#tblBody').html(object);
                }
                else {
                    var object = '';
                    $.each(response, function (Index, item) {
                        object += '<tr>';
                        object += '<td > ' + item.TeamId + '</td>';
                        object += '<td > ' + item.TeamName + '</td>';
                        object += '<td > ' + item.Owner + '</td>';
                        object += '<td > ' + item.couchName + '</td>';
                        object += '</td>';
                        object += '</tr>';

                    });
                    $('#tblBody').html(object);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Unable to Read Team Data13223');
            }
        }
    )}
```

Here it is `index` file:

```
@model TournamentManagementSystem.Models.Team
 
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Team List";
}
<h3>@ViewData["Title"] </h3>

<hr />
<div>

    <button class="  btn btn-primary "  id="btnAdd">Add Team</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-success table-striped table-responsive table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>  Id   </th>
                <th>  Team Name   </th>
                <th>  Owner Name   </th>
                <th>  Coach    </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tblBody"> 
    </table>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script  src="/js/site.js"> </script>
}
```

Here is the controller code
...

namespace TournamentManagementSystem.Controllers
{
public class TeamController : Controller

```
{
    // GET: TeamController
    public readonly WebApplication11Context context;

    public TeamController(WebApplication11Context db)
    {
        context = db;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    public JsonResult GetTeams()
    {
        var team = context.Teams.ToList();
        return Json(team);
    }
}
```

}
...

Table display:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq8BB.png)

Comment: In your browser’s debugging tools, observe the response to the AJAX request.  What does it contain?  JavaScript is case sensitive, perhaps the property names aren’t what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the method `Json(obj)` is that it serializes object properties to lowercase.
In your JQuery code, you could use the json properties in their lower case

```
$.each(response, function (Index, item) {
      object += '<tr>';
      object += '<td > ' + item.teamId + '</td>';
      object += '<td > ' + item.teamName + '</td>';
      object += '<td > ' + item.owner + '</td>';
      object += '<td > ' + item.coachName + '</td>';
      object += '</td>';
      object += '</tr>';
});
```

Note that there was a typo in `coachName` in your code.

Alternatively, you could use the over load of `Json` method that takes `JsonSerializerOptions` as a parameter

```
var serializerOptions= new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
};

return Json(team, serializerOptions);
```

Comment: thanks ,,problem solved ,,thanks a lot dear